# Can iMessage send a video as-is, without converting it first?

Tags: ios, messages, video, encoding

If I share a video file via iMessage, the recipient doesn't get the exact file I've shared, but a converted version of the video, which has a lower resolution and lower quality (e.g. when I share a 1080p H.265 video, iMessage actually sends a 300p H.264 blurry mess.)

Is there a way to make iMessage share a video without re-encoding it? What are the technical criteria that video files have to meet in order to be spared re-encoding? (codecs, profiles, resolution, file size)

I know I could share a URL to a file hosted elsewhere, but I want to have end-to-end encryption, and I don't want to require the recipient to perform any unusual steps or leave iMessage to view the video.

Comment: What about zipping the file up before sharing?

Comment: @JMY1000 Would a zip file play in Messages.app? My recipient is on iOS and is completely non-technical.

Comment: I see. No, unfortunately it would not.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think we get to directly influence this.

For my threat model, I’m not super concerned if iCloud and Apple can decrypt the attachments stored in iCloud, so I typically save the video to iCloud shared photo album and share a link. If you’re sharing copyright content or something you don’t wish the government to get at via a cell carrier I understand not wanting to upload that to a server.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204042
- https://support.apple.com/guide/security/imessage-overview-secd9764312f/web

Also, be sure your carrier settings are updated, some carriers influenced sending quality in the past, but I haven’t seen that happen lately in the US.

The function of iCloud and Messages/FaceTime varies greatly based on what region your device was sold and what region you associate your AppleID. Even in the US, Apple may upload the content of your messages to their servers, E2E encryption may not be compromised substantially when you are sending large attachments.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209110

If you need end-to-end encryption, letting the video be compressed might be the lesser of two evils.

Comment: I don’t believe iCloud shared photo albums have E2E encryption

Comment: In my case sender and recipient use the latest iOS or latest macOS. I'm not in the US.

Comment: Fair points, I am not sure we get to control this directly. Apple seems to let carriers influence data rates but not easily intercept the data being exchanged and it does very substantially based on region. I’ll update my answer with Apple services matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Apple tends to convert videos in iMessage for the following reasons:

1. When the file size is really large
2. When the device you are sending the video to doesn't support the high resolution.
3. If the sender or the receiver are on a slow network or using cellular data (rather than wifi).
4. Apple doesn't want you to send large video files through iMessage and instead use a cloud video or file hosting service to send such files.

(I personally use [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/) on my computer to compress the videos myself and try to match the quality to the receipients device, before sending it through iMessage. And try to keep the video file size less than 20 MB for best results.)

I think a better option for you would be [Mega App](https://apps.apple.com/in/app/mega/id706857885#?platform=iphone) & cloud storage service.